# Ansible ec2_asg module does not find launch configuration

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get Ansible to create a launch configuration (using `ec2_lc`) and auto scaling group (`ec2_asg`). My playbook creates the launch configuration just fine, but the ASG is creating an error:

`fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No launch config found with name {'name': 'dockerLC', 'instance_type': 't2.micro', 'image_id': 'ami-e97c548c', 'changed': False, 'failed': False, 'arn': None, 'created_time': 'None', 'security_groups': ['sg-e0c0de88'], 'result': {'image_id': 'ami-e97c548c', 'key_name': 'ansible-keys', 'launch_configuration_name': 'dockerLC', 'ebs_optimized': False, 'instance_type': 't2.micro', 'created_time': 'None', 'associate_public_ip_address': True, 'instance_monitoring': False, 'placement_tenancy': 'default', 'security_groups': ['sg-e0c0de88'], 'block_device_mappings': []}}"}`

I'm unsure why this error is being thrown because I certainly have a `dockerLC` launch configuration in the AWS EC2 web interface. My playbook is below.

```
  tasks:
    - name: Create Launch Configuration
      local_action:
        module: ec2_lc
        name: dockerLC
        region: '{{ aws_region }}'
        image_id: '{{ ami_id }}'
        key_name: '{{ key_name }}'
        security_groups: '{{ security_group_id }}'
        # security_groups: '{{ security_group }}'
        instance_type: '{{ instance_type }}'
        assign_public_ip: True
        vpc_id: '{{ vpc }}'
      register: lc
    # - pause:
    #     seconds: 10
    - name: Create Auto Scaling Group
      local_action:
        module: ec2_asg
        name: dockerASG
        region: '{{ aws_region }}'
        launch_config_name: '{{ lc }}'
        min_size: 3
        max_size: 5
        wait_for_instances: True
        availability_zones: ['us-east-2a', 'us-east-2b', 'us-east-2c']
        vpc_zone_identifier: ' {{ vpc_zones }} '
        tags:
          - function: docker
            billingGroup: Work
```

Answer (score 0):

When you register a variable for tasks the variable is usually a hash containing more information than just a string. In this case, there is a hash containing:

```
{  
   'name':'dockerLC',
   'instance_type':'t2.micro',
   'image_id':'ami-e97c548c',
   'changed':False,
   'failed':False,
   'arn':None,
   'created_time':'None',
   'security_groups':[  
      'sg-e0c0de88'
   ],
   'result':{  
      'image_id':'ami-e97c548c',
      'key_name':'ansible-keys',
      'launch_configuration_name':'dockerLC',
      'ebs_optimized':False,
      'instance_type':'t2.micro',
      'created_time':'None',
      'associate_public_ip_address':True,
      'instance_monitoring':False,
      'placement_tenancy':'default',
      'security_groups':[  
         'sg-e0c0de88'
      ],
      'block_device_mappings':[  

      ]
   }
}
```

But `launch_config_name` wants just the name as a string. In this case, you want to reference `launch_config_name: '{{ lc.name }}'` which is the name of the launch configuration. You could likely also use the ariable `lc.result.launch_configuration_name` as well (as an example).